# Using a 4 wire 240v 30A circuit to power a 2 wire 240v device

Tags: wiring

I have a 240v 30a circuit with a 4 prong 14-30 receptacle installed in my garage.  I'd like to connect a 240v baseboard heater that requires L1 (hot) and a neutral and a ground.  Since the circuit consists of 2 120v leads (red and black) is there a way to safely connect both to the single lead on the baseboard heater?

Comment: Are you sure it requires a neutral?  A 240 v heater should use 2 hot leads and a ground.

Comment: Is this heater intended for the North American or the European market?

Comment: The notion of tying red+black together shows how little you know about electrical, which is fine. Except, you're also using terms-of-art in a fairly precise manner, and you have created an unclear situation:  You say the heater is 240V, *and* you say it has a hot and neutral, *and* you don't say it's European. These things contradict each other.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The heater is for US market.  It is rated as 240v 2500W

Comment: The circuit diagram shows two connections: a single black wire to which your connect L1.  And the second connection consisting of a blue control wire (unit has a built-in thermostat/control panel) and a black element wire where the instructions say you connect "L2/Neutral".

Comment: Harper,  The cord I have is 10 AGW rated for 600v, water resistant rubber cased housing a black wire, a white wire and a green wire.  The plug is a standard 14-30P which be used for 30 amp or 50 amp.  I have a strain relief squeeze connector sized to the cord that fits the heater knockout.  I choose to cord the unit so I did not have to go through the trouble of opening the wall to run wire to hard-wire.

Comment: The manufacture Dimplex model PC6025W3.  The installation instructions are available at this link:  http://www.dimplex.com/cms/publications/7213200100R03_EN_-_Website.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NEMA 14 is the universal donor

Your NEMA 14-30 connector is the type you want.  It has

- neutral (white or gray, 120V to L1 or L2),
- Safety Ground (green, green/ehite or bare, near 0V to neutral, near 120V to a hot)
- both hots (any color yet unnamed, same color ok, black and red commonly, L1 and L2, 240V across them)

### What voltage is this thing?

You need to look at the machine's nameplate and see what it actually is. What's more, get the manufacturer's instructions for the unit and see what it says.  It is illegal to connect it contrary to the manufacturer instructions, and that makes it illegal to fail to read them.

US-market *large* heaters (2000W and up) are made for 240 volts, needing to connect to L1 and L2.  They do not use neutral.   Many smaller heaters made for permanent installation are also 240V.

US-market *small* heaters are often 120V.  If they are 120V, they have a hot (either L1 or L2, never both) and neutral.

European and rest-of-world heaters are all 230/240V, because everything there is 230/240V.  Most will tolerate 240V because they're built to be compatible with the UK and some Asian nations which are 240V rather than 230V. Unlike us, they have 240V between hot and neutral.  They use brown for hot, and blue for neutral.  First, you must check the instructions or with the manufacturer as to whether they allow North American style hot-hot connections. If they do, connect brown to L1 and blue to L2, or vice versa.

You also connect a ground wire, always.  Doing it bare 2-wire is not allowed, unless the heater is *listed* as double-insulated, which it will say rather directly if it does, because they had to pay a lot of money to have it certified as such.  Don't assume this.

### Cord-and-plug connected, or hard-wired

You can only go cord-and-plug if *it makes sense* for the thing to be portable. But then, you can fab it yourself.  You need to visit a *real electrical supply house* and obtain proper *cordage*, which is special electrical cable made to be a cord. The size of the required wire depends on the rating of the heater.  Then you need proper *strain relief* on the appliance end, and a good fitting plug on the wall end.  Getting right stuff that matches is the reason to go to a proper electrical supply; they can do it; big-box can't.

If it's hard-wired, you will need to go to your town and pull a permit, then have it inspected when you're done.  If you're not super good at this (and you aren't yet), the second one may be the way to go, because a set of smart eyes will look it over for you.  On the other hand, if you're doing something you should not, he can shut the whole thing down.  Also in most jurisdictions you must hire an electrician for units you are renting out, or if you have been banned for being really bad at it.

If you hardwire it, you need to run 10 AWG wire, since your circuit breaker is 30A.

Answer (score 1):

> **Since the circuit consists of 2 120v leads (red and black) is there a way to safely connect both to the single lead on the baseboard heater?**

No.

There's no safe way to directly connect your two US split-phase 120V leads together. That is a short circuit and your main panel's circuit breaker would try really hard to save your house from burning down.

It might be possible to connect the appliance's "neutral" to one of your 120V leads but to be sure you should check the appliance manual, contact the manufacturer or edit your question to include make and model of appliance. Your appliance might be unhappy that "neutral" is 120V from ground.

Answer (score -6):

You NEED 4 wires not 3, you simply have a 110 service on that receptacle.  Get an electrician to upgrade this receptacle.  Check to see if your heater needs 4 wires to work or is it a 110 heater that only needs 3 wire.  Make sure you've got 12 gauge wire...really get an electrician to do this...unless your regulations say 'Anyone can do electrical with inspection and approval'...I've never heard of homeowners getting away with doing their own electrical work or their friends and having their homeowners insurance good with that kind of work.  What are the rules/regulations from your city's buildings and code?

Comment: In many states it is legal for home owners to do there own wiring as long as it meets code and permits are pulled.

Comment: Seconding Ed Beal here -- it matters far more how well the work's done vs. who does the work -- bone up on the Code and make something you're rightfully proud to show the inspectors, and most of them won't care about qualifications at that point.  (Besides, the pros are only human...)

Comment: Welp wonderful, but I'd like to hear from your home owner's insurance.  You've got to get the general contractor to sign, the inspectors are kind of worthless like not accountable for errors!!  I'd like to hear from your Buildings and Code as well.  Makes no sense to me.  And if the General signs it means HE IS RESPONSIBLE.  My entire point was for the home owner to FIND OUT what the rules are!!  To know what the ramifications are for someone not licensed to do any electrical work to do any part of the install and who is responsible if say a fire was started because of faulty wiring.

Comment: Hate to tell you guys it is far more important to insurance companies to have it very clear who is responsible for a boo boo!  Amazing.  City inspectors are essentially WORTHLESS.  Just getting a permit well and good but you have a fire those city inspectors ARE NOT ACCOUNTABLE.  Good grief.  What states do you guys live in?  Have you checked this out personally or is this just what you've seen or been through.  Trust me, THEY will love you to do your own work, perhaps get 'passed' for occupancy but if your home burns down they will not at all be accountable or there for you.

Comment: For most work of this type (i.e. installing a hardwired device) -- *there is no general contractor involved* -- either the homeowner or the electrician pulls the permit (if one is required for this type of work by the AHJ).  (There's nothing stopping you from pulling a permit for work you're contracting out to an electrician/plumber/...)

Comment: Yes, to become the General versus Sub, you will be doing more than ONE service.  Totally different venues, licenses and bonding.  Insurance companies LOVE this DIY stuff.  All I am saying is go out and find your state's or county's or city's rules and regs.  They will love it when YOU screw up and they do not cover you within your contract.  Gees.  All you need to do is go find what the dang rules truly are, don't make them up by yourself.

Comment: OP stated that his outlet is a 14-30. This is not a 110 volt circuit!

Comment: OP also see rated it's a 30 amp circuit, yet your answer @stormy specifies 12 gauge wire.

Comment: You should use  12 gauge for a 30 amp circuit.  3 wires usually means 110 or 120volts.  4 wires are typically used to implement a 220 or 240 volt service. Maybe I am not counting his wires.  I am not an expert with electricity at all but this sounds pretty crazy.  If the OP doesn't understand this any better than me he should get an ELECTRICIAN!  Baseboard heaters that are 220/240volts are usually hardwired, only the dang oven and dryer use pigtails...maybe a hot water heater?  I am just amazed people think they can get away with doing electrical by themselves with their insurance ok with that

Comment: I'll restate this: city, county inspectors are NOT ACCOUNTABLE for anything they say or do.  Just because you get passed for your DIY electrical install, I seriously doubt the insurance company will care.  In fact, they will love it because they are essentially off the hook and safe.  But the home owner is not.  Why am I not being understood?  And, trust me I am not being emotional at all, just very curious as to why you guys think someone should do their own work, especially with 220/240 volts and expect their insurance company will be ok with that?  Again, where does the OP live?

Comment: "You should use 12 gauge for a 30 amp circuit" Please cite what part of the NEC authorizes that.

Comment: Are you wanting the minimum or maximum?  I always go for maximum or the safe side.  As long as I can get by using the best gauge wire, heck 12 gauge is what I use.  I'll go check MY jurisdiction's code, ok?  Gosh, I do not know the world's rules and regulations.  I only know the Pacific NW of two states and 12 gauge works best.  Unless we aren't talking about the same thing.  We are on a 30 amp circuit in the Pacific NW and 12 gauge is great.  What do you see that is wrong via NEC regs?

Comment: Why not use just 12 gauge without worrying about stepping down to 14?  How much MORE cost would it be to do ALL 12 gauge?  Is it really that big of a deal?